# function consumption optimization in python

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a function that receives a list of integers and what each integer does is build a json, consume some api, do validations and then insert it into a database. But there is a problem, with a list of 2 values the function takes seconds but with a list of 200 values it takes minutes more than 8 minutes, is it possible to optimize that time by sending that amount of values? , it is possible to send a series of values so that the function does its job and at the same time send another amount of values and that the function does its job and thus, simultaneously send, for example, 50 values to the function and then send other 50 to the same function at the same time to optimize time? or how would be the ideal way to optimize it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally there are two approaches. Optimizing the process for a single call and running multiple calls at once also known as parallelization.

For optimizing a single call, you should start by profiling the function. Python has a built-in profiler, [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html). There are other packages as well such as [py-spy](https://github.com/benfred/py-spy) which can have the results formatted to be integrated into https://www.speedscope.app/ which is a nice visual tool.

Regarding parallelization, it depends on how this function is used. You could take a look at [Asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html). However if you're hitting the database, that's probably going to prove difficult and you'll need to [integrate Django Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/databases.html) or something similar. Django is still working on proper Async DB functionality. Alternatively, you can use something like [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/) and wrap this function in a Task. Then you can schedule calls with various arguments and scale up the workers as needed.

Hopefully this helps you on your search and understanding of how to build what you need.